# Where to put return in python

Tags: python-3.x, return

> ```
> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
> for element in x:
> return element
> ```

gives IndentationError: expected an indented block

> ```
> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
> for element in x:
>      return element
> ```

gives error>>> SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define this in a function and call that function for the return value. Something like this -

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
def find_element():
for element in x:
     return element
a = find_element()
print (a)
```

Code - https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/MGO9MBWFyz

Answer (score 0):

A return statement is used to end the execution of the function call:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
def fun():
    for element in x:
         return element
```

You can also return multiple values from a function.

```
    return a,b,c
```